# Constant log messages on BlueZ Bluetooth application: 'Bluetooth: hci0: security requested but not available'

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have developed a BLE application for a RaspberryPI and a corresponding iPhone application. This was written based on the example-gatt-server from blueZ. It uses the dbus interface.

While the application seems to work just fine, /var/syslog is showing the following error message at an alarming rate (20+/second)

```
 [ 9092.323282] Bluetooth: hci0: security requested but not available
```

The continue until the Bluetooth is turned off on the iPhone.

EDIT: **I've found that if I do a hciconfig hci0 reset on boot (or anytime?), the error messages stop and do not resume.**

Here is the results of btmon:

```
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #213 [hci0] 6.142424
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                                                                                        #215 [hci0] 6.143344
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #216 [hci0] 6.202355
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #218 [hci0] 6.262408
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                                                                                        #220 [hci0] 6.263288
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #221 [hci0] 6.322406
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #223 [hci0] 6.382385
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                                                                                        #225 [hci0] 6.383242
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #226 [hci0] 6.442419
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #228 [hci0] 6.502417
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                                                                                        #230 [hci0] 6.503334
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #231 [hci0] 6.562415
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #233 [hci0] 6.622434
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
 HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                                                                                        #235 [hci0] 6.623311
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                                                                                                                    #236 [hci0] 6.682441
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Read Request (0x0a)
        Handle: 0x0016
        Error: Insufficient Encryption (0x0f)
```

Comment: Can you run "btmon &" to see the HCI logs as that might provide more information.

Comment: @YoussifSaeed I've added info to the question.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an XBox controller and a Beaglebone except mine doesn't work at all.